# show different view with different tap count from UIBarButtonItem (wrap an UISegmentedControl)

Tags: ipad, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch, tap

i have read about UITouch and UIGestureRecognizer, but i still really confused what the difference between them. 
I have one case. In my app, i have a barbuttonitem, i want to show different view when a tap that button. if i do a singletap, i want to show a textview, but when i do a singletap again, i want to show a popover from that button. is there somebody can give me an example code to do it and give a little explanation about what is the difference between UITouch and UIGestureRecognizer???

**UPDATE**

the barbuttonitem is a wrapper of UISegmentedControl, here's a pic from the desain 
[image]

i was try to use touchesBegan:withEvent: and touchesEnded:withEvent: to solve this problem, but i dont know how to connect it to that barbuttonitem.
This is the code i made :

```
-(void)addSegment{


NSAutoreleasePool *pool;
int count_doc = [_docsegmentmodels count];
NSLog(@"count doc add segment : %d", count_doc);
pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
DocSegmentedModel *sl;
NSMutableArray *segmentTextMutable = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i=0 ;(i<count_doc && i < max_segment);i++){
    sl = [_docsegmentmodels objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *evalString = [[KoderAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] setStringWithLength:sl.docSegmentFileName:10];  
    [segmentTextMutable addObject:NSLocalizedString(evalString,@"")];

}



NSArray *segmentText = [segmentTextMutable copy];

_docSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentText];
_docSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0; 
_docSegmentedControl.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
_docSegmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled;//UISegmentedControlStylePlain;// UISegmentedControlStyleBar;//UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled;
//docSegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 46.0);
[_docSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(docSegmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

// Add the control to the navigation bar
//UIBarButtonItem *segmentItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_docSegmentedControl];
segmentItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_docSegmentedControl];
self.navItem.leftBarButtonItem = segmentItem;
self.navItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = @"";


[pool release];
[segmentItem release];
[_docSegmentedControl release];
```

}

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self 
                                         selector:@selector(segmentItemTapped:) object:segmentItem];
```

}

```
-(void)touchesEnd:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
if (touches.count == 1) {
    if (theTouch.tapCount == 2) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(segmentItemTapped:)withObject:segmentItem afterDelay:0.35];
    }else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(docSegmentAction:) withObject:segmentItem afterDelay:0.0];
    }
}
```

}

```
- (IBAction)segmentItemTapped:(id)sender{  

if (self.fileProperties == nil) {
    self.fileProperties = [[[FilePropertiesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FilePropertiesViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    fileProperties.delegate = self;
    self.filePropertiesPopover = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:fileProperties]autorelease];
    [_docsegmentmodels objectAtIndex:_docSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
}

fileProperties.docProperties = _docsegmentmodels;
fileProperties.index = _docSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex; //index utk nilai2 di textfield
[self.filePropertiesPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender 
                                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                                   animated:YES];
```

}

```
- (IBAction)docSegmentAction:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"open file");
isFileOpen = YES;
[self.moreFilePopOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
[self.filePropertiesPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

[self showTextView];
```

}

is there any mistake in my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't need UIGestureRecognizer. Simply set the action of the barbuttonitem to the method that should be called when the button is tapped.  Have the method keep track of the state of the textview and depending on it show it or show the popover.

Comment: i still think that i have to use the UITouch or UIGestureRecognizer, because the barbuttonitem is made programmatically, and it is a wrapper of UISegmentedControl, i'm sorry to not declare it in my question, but i still confuse about it